# Dynamic Programming - Print all paths from (0,0) to (n,n) in Grid/Lattice

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, enumeration

I'm trying to write an algorithm to print all the paths from point (0,0) to (n,n) in a grid.
The only possible moves are *right* and *up*.
Also, you can't move below the diagonal *y=x*. e.g if you're at (1,1) you can only move to *(1,2)*, but not to *(2,1)*, since it's below the *y=x* diagonal.

I wrote an algorithm that calculates the number of possible paths from *(0,0)* to any given *(x,y)*, such that the above limitations are held, but I can't find a way to print out the paths that give these numbers.

The algorithm I wrote is a *bottom-up* one, as follows:

```
JUMP(x, y)
1.  M[x-1,y+1] ← 1 
2.  for i=0 to x+1
        M[i,y+1] ← 0
3.  for i=0 to y+1
        M[x+1,i] ← 0
4.  for j=0 to y-1
        for i=j+1 to x
            M[i,j] ← 0

5.  for j=y to 0
        for i=j to 0
            M[i,j] ← M[i+1,j] + M[i,j+1]

6.  return M[i,j]
```

Please advise on this.

Comment: Printing *all* paths is often a bad idea (w.r.t. resources) but here's a hint: after filling the table, retrace the steps you've taken.

Comment: The *number* of paths is given by the Catalan numbers.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I know how to get the number of paths (both via a top-down approach as well as a bottom-up one), and that's covered pretty nicely online. The problem is when trying to print out all the paths that get you from point A to point B, which I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around on.

Comment: @Raphael Retracing one paths back is pretty simple as well, as you can just save a general pi array of size n*n and trace your way "back" from (n,n) to (0,0) using it. However, printing **all** the paths from (0,0) to (n,n) is the hard part here.

Comment: @The_Ben The technique for printing one path can be extended to print all paths. Note that using DP for this task is unnecessary; its power lies in *not* examining all solutions. Just do DFS with backtracking or something similar.

Comment: @Raphael I'm sorry, but I don't understand how you can find *all* paths from point A to point B in the lattice. Running BFS/DFS from (0,0) will give you *one* path from A to B (when backtracking using the pi array), but not *all* paths from A to B.

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this problem using a recursive formulation of print all paths from a point $(i,j)$ to the target $(n,n)$ in the grid. I call this function $f(i,j)$. So the all paths will be in $f(0,0)$ call.

$f(i,j) = \begin{cases}
\emptyset & if\ \ {i>j}\\
\emptyset & if\ \ \neg( {0\leq i\leq n\ \wedge 0\leq j\leq n) }\\
\{(n,n)\} & if \ \ i = n \wedge j = n\\
\bigcup_{p\,\in\, f(i+1,j)\,\cup\,f(i,j+1) } \ \ \{(i,j)\}\cup p & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

By example, two of all paths from $f(0,0)$ when $n=4$ are:

blue path = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
  4}}

red path = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 
  4}}

[image]

So, although programming is not in the scope of this site, I think is good to see a implementation for a memoization version of the above algorithm.
asdf

```
from functools import wraps

def memo(func):
    cache = {}

    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = func(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return wrap

@memo
def f(i, j):
    global n
    if i > j:
        return []
    if not (0 <= i <= n and 0 <= j <= n):
        return []
    if i == n and j == n:
        return [[(n,n)]]
    alls = []
    for path in f(i, j+1)+f(i+1, j):
        if len(path) > 0:
            alls += [[(i,j)] + path] 
    return alls

n = 4
for path in f(0,0):
    print path
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be a good solution, but what is the time complexity of it? Isn't it O(2^(n*n))? Seems a bit high when doing this recursively. Also, do you know of any bottom-up approach to solve this (rather than top-down like you did above, with memoization).

Comment: You seem to be right about complexity, btw generate all paths is usually expensive for graphs, like in this case, your lattice. And, for a bottom-up approach, may be you can do a Breath First Search in the lattice asserting all conditions about monotonic paths.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an $x$ by $y$ grid (assuming we start at the bottom-left and travel toward the upper-right), you can notice that every possible path will always contain $x$ steps toward the right and $y$ steps upward. You could encode every possible path with a binary string of length $x+y$ where $0$ encodes "right" and $1$ encodes "up", and there are exactly $x$ $0$'s and exactly $y$ $1$'s in the string.

To solve the problem, you could follow this procedure:

- take a binary string of length $x+y$, starting with all $0$'s
- check if the string has $y$ bits equal to $1$
- if so, print the path the string represents, with $0$ = "right" and $1$ = "up"
- incrememt the binary string by $1$ and repeat

In pseudocode:

```
x = 7; //the grid is x by y in size
y = 9; 
N = x+y; //length of the binary string

for i from 0 to (2^N)-1:
  if NumberOfOnes(i,N) == y:
    PrintPath(i,N);
```

To check if the least-significant bit is a `1`, we can just take `i mod 2` and check if the result is a `1`. We can check bit `j` in the same way just by bit-shifting `j` bits to to the right and repeating the processes.

```
function NumberOfOnes(i,N)
  ones = 0;
  zeroes = 0;
  bit = 0;
  for j from N-1 to 0
    temp = i >> j;     //ensures we read the string from left-to-right
    if (temp mod 2) == 1
     ones++
    else
     zeros++
    if zeros > ones  // this protects us from moving below the diagonal
     ones = -1;
     break;
  return ones
```

To print the string we use a similar process to find the `1`'s and let `0` mean "right" and `1` mean "up". We also need to read the string left-to-right.

```
function PrintPath(i,N)
  path_string = [empty]
  for j from N-1 to 0
    temp = i >> j          //ensures we read the string left-to-right
    if (temp mod 2) == 1
      path_string += 'up, '
    else
      path_string += 'right, '

  print(path_string)
```

This involves checking $2^{x+y}$ binary numbers and performing $x+y$ bit-shifts on each one.

Also for counting the paths, you can notice that the number of acceptable binary strings is just ${x + y \choose y}/2$ since we have $x+y$ binary digits and need to choose $y$ of them to be $1$, and divide by $2$ to ignore paths below the diagonal.

Comment: For $x=y=3$ this will print (simplifying a bit) URRURU, but that wouldn't be allowed, since the OP stated that no paths can be below the main diagonal.

Comment: @RickDecker--good point. I added some extra code `NumberOfOnes()` to ignore these cases and some code in `PrintPath()` to read the string in the proper direction.

Comment: @eigenchris This seems like it would work, but kind of "runs around the whole idea", doesn't it? I mean, you're solving an equivalent problem, but not the same problem. I need to use dynamic programming here, which your suggested solution isn't written by (this is an interview question).

Comment: @The_Ben I didn't realize you were constrained to use dynamic programming. It's true that my solution is very specific to this problem and doesn't follow any sort of general bottom-up or top-down approach you would use to tackle algorithm problems in general, so it's not very instructional in that sense. However my solution has $O(2^{2n})$ complexity so I thought it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: @The_Ben As Raphael has pointed out, DP represents a scheme to intelligently reuse interim results in an optimization setting. There is nothing to optimize here as you are requested - in sloppy phrasing - to enumerate the complete search space. So you might have been asked a trick question.

Comment: @eigenchris It's definitely worth mentioning, thanks. I was sure than my title mentioned dynamic programming, but is seems like I forgot to write it. I'll add it now.

Comment: @collapsar So how would you go about doing it in dynamic programming (especially bottom-up if possible)? I still can't figure out how to print all paths this way unfortunately.